# i want to get the results from mongodb collection using date range "utc_timestamp" field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

My question consist of two parts

1. i want to collect the data from mongodb using date range (from date
   and to date).
2. Secondly i need day wise data from my collection within the date range?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IFO9.png)

Comment: you should add a couple of sample documents from your db and the expected result to your question to make it easy for people to help you isntead of posting a picture.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IFO9.png here is the link of sample document

Comment: results  are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Comparison Query Operators?

**$eq** Matches values that are equal to a specified value.

**$gt** Matches values that are greater than a specified value.

**$gte**    Matches values that are greater than or equal to a specified value.

**$in** Matches any of the values specified in an array.

**$lt** Matches values that are less than a specified value.

**$lte**    Matches values that are less than or equal to a specified value.

**$ne** Matches all values that are not equal to a specified value.

**$nin**    Matches none of the values specified in an array.

**Example 1** ,

```
db.collectionName.find({
    utc_timestamp: {
        $gte: new Date("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

**Example 2** ,

```
db.collectionName.find({
  utc_timestamp: {
    $gte: {
      $dateFromString: {
        dateString: '$utc_timestamp'
      }$lt: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: '$utc_timestamp'
        }
      }
    })
```